# Do you need a visa when transitting in UK with a foreign passport and a residence permit

Tags: uk, transit, transit-visas

I hold a Danish foreign passport and a residence permit and will be travelling from Copenhagen to Fuerteventura with a transit in UK, but im unsure whether I need a visa or not...
Your prompt attention to this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a *Danish foreign passport*?

Comment: In addition to making your citizenship clearer, it will also be necessary to know if your two flights are on the same ticket or if they were booked separately.